# AngularJS - Bind to Scroll (Mousewheel, Dragging Bar, and Touch Swiping)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, angularjs

I made a very shabby "Infinite-Scroll" directive, all other solutions were incompatible with a md-grid-list so I went ahead and made my own alternative workaround.

```
app.directive('scrollTrigger', function($window) {
  return {
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var e = angular.element(element[0]);
      e.bind('mousewheel', function() {
        var parent = e.offsetParent()[0];
        if (parent.scrollTop + parent.offsetHeight > (70/100*parent.scrollHeight)) {
          scope.$apply(attrs.scrollTrigger);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

You simply put `scroll-trigger` on the html element that will be scrollable. The code checks if it has been scrolled to atleast 70% down, if it has, then it will trigger whatevers called on the scroll-trigger, for example: scroll-trigger="loadMore()"

This works fine but it ONLY works if you use the Mousewheel, but what if users without a mousewheel try using my website? They cant continue loading more items.

The ways that dont work are:

- Manually dragging the scrollbar
- Swiping/Dragging Up/Down on a Touch Device

Working ways:

- Using the Mousewheel

And yes, I do know why, im only binding with e.bind('mousewheel') this is because "scroll" wouldnt actually work for me at all.

So im kinda unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Have you tried to bind on the 'scroll' event instead of 'mousewheel'?

Comment: @P.Ommer I have and when using the scroll event even scrolling using the bar doesnt actually trigger anything. (Tested on Chrome)

Comment: I've tried it and for me it's working.
Here is my fast test: http://jsfiddle.net/csGUe/1/